# Single.php for Custom Post Type > Taxonomy > Term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a custom post type - Films. It has a taxonomy of Film_cat, which in turn has two terms/categories - Term1 & Term2.

For each single post within Term1, I would like to display a specific single.php template. Each single post within Term2 should also have it's own single.php template.

I am currently utilising taxonomy-film_cat-term1.php for the taxonomy archives templates, however can't find any info on how to create different single.php templates based on the taxonomy term.

Effectively, I need a single.php template for a Custom Post Type > Taxonomy > Taxonomy Term.

Answer (score 1):

You can load a different template for single posts via the [`single_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) filter. Just use the [`has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function to check if the post has a specific term in your custom taxonomy.

```
function wpa_107626_single_template( $single_template ) {
     // check if the post fits some condition
     if ( has_term( 'term1', 'film_cat' ) ) {
          $single_template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-term1.php';
     }
     return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpa_107626_single_template' ) ;
```

Comment: +1. Why no global $post;?

Comment: Why, is it not working? The third/last parameter of [`has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) is `$post` and by default is always set to the current post, so I don't think you need to global `$post`.

Comment: Works well, just curious about the use of global $post;

Comment: Cool. I think it is covered by the 3rd parameter of `has_term()`.